# Where should I setup the database when dockerizing a node application?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, containers, orchestration

I've a backend application running on node and mongodb. I wanted to shift my application to docker so I've dockerized node but I'm confused where should I run mongodb or should I dockerize it or not.

**Note: I want to do this for production environment**

Here are some scenarios, I've thought of:

1. Run node in docker container and mongodb in local machine
2. Run both node and database in docker containers and store the data in the container same as database
3. Run node and database in docker containers and store the data in separate volume

**Which scenario is the best to implement on production server?**

*I'm new to docker so **if you have other solution to this problem, consider mentioning it.** Also you can involve **kubernetes** in the scenarios if needed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of this two solution:

- Create a deployment for your node js server and use a local mongodb , connection estabilished via your host ip (but this only valide for developement ) . To use this solution for production you should create and setup a public @ip address to esure the TCP connection between mongo and node js app .
- The Second solution is to create a deployment for your node js server and a statfulset for your mongodb database and use (pv,pvc,storageclasse) to persist your data .

I have a demo using mongo ,redis and nodejs (express app) that you can follow to resolve your issue
Follow my example [here](https://github.com/radhouen/products-store).

Comment: You don't need and should not create public facing databases. This is a huge security risk. Unless by "public" you mean "outside of container system, but inside local network".
Please, do not create public facing databases, this is how data leaks happen.

Comment: Yes I mean outside container (Inside Virtual machine in your local network ) , Thanks for your clearification .

Answer (score 1):

Two of your scenarios are how things usually work on prod:

> 1. Run node in docker container and mongodb in local machine

This is how we did in in my previous job. Applications inside containers and databases on separate VMs. It worked quite well, can't say much more about it.

> 2. Run both node and database in docker containers and store the data in the container same as database

**Do not** do this. Containers are ephemeral - that means all data inside is gone once the container is deleted. That includes databases and records inside databases.

> 3. Run node and database in docker containers and store the data in separate volume

This is another correct way to do this, probably the one that is most widely accepted. If you decide to go this way, you may want to read up on [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for Docker or [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) and [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) for Kubernetes